# Git Bash and webpack

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, git-bash

Hello guys I'm trying to learn Webpack I've been following some tutorials and I've run into some problems. I've installed webpack locally in folder I am working in with `npm install webpack --save-dev`. I made two JS scripts and I wanted to bundle them and I've tried following command `webpack script-1.js /.bundle.js` in WindowsPowerShell (I'm using Windows 7). Now this made the following error

> webpack is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

So then I installed webpack globally, and when I used the same command in PowerShell (I have opened it as an admin), it made bundle.js file but not in the directory I was working in, but in C:
Now after this failure I've decided to try using git bash. First I've tried this command `webpack script-1.js /.bundle.js` and got the following error

> bash: webpack: command not found

Finally after some trying I was able to make it work using this command in git bash `node_modules/.bin/webpack ./script-1.js bundle.js`
Is there a way to fix this, so I can just type webpack instead of whole path ? Also is there a way to fix path in PowerShell ?

This is mine package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack-playlist",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/iamshaunjp/webpack-playlist.git"
  },
  "author": "me",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/iamshaunjp/webpack-playlist/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/iamshaunjp/webpack-playlist#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^2.3.3"
  }
}
```

and this is package.json located in node_modules/webpack/package.json

```
{
  "_args": [
    [
      {
        "raw": "webpack",
        "scope": null,
        "escapedName": "webpack",
        "name": "webpack",
        "rawSpec": "",
        "spec": "latest",
        "type": "tag"
      },
      "C:\\Users\\Djole\\Desktop\\NetNinja\\webpack-playlist"
    ]
  ],
  "_from": "webpack@latest",
  "_id": "webpack@2.3.3",
  "_inCache": true,
  "_location": "/webpack",
  "_nodeVersion": "7.4.0",
  "_npmOperationalInternal": {
    "host": "packages-12-west.internal.npmjs.com",
    "tmp": "tmp/webpack-2.3.3.tgz_1491205859622_0.6350918470416218"
  },
  "_npmUser": {
    "name": "sokra",
    "email": "tobias.koppers@googlemail.com"
  },
  "_npmVersion": "4.0.5",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "raw": "webpack",
    "scope": null,
    "escapedName": "webpack",
    "name": "webpack",
    "rawSpec": "",
    "spec": "latest",
    "type": "tag"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "#DEV:/",
    "#USER"
  ],
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack/-/webpack-2.3.3.tgz",
  "_shasum": "eecc083c18fb7bf958ea4f40b57a6640c5a0cc78",
  "_shrinkwrap": null,
  "_spec": "webpack",
  "_where": "C:\\Users\\Djole\\Desktop\\NetNinja\\webpack-playlist",
  "author": {
    "name": "Tobias Koppers @sokra"
  },
  "bin": {
    "webpack": "./bin/webpack.js"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "acorn": "^4.0.4",
    "acorn-dynamic-import": "^2.0.0",
    "ajv": "^4.7.0",
    "ajv-keywords": "^1.1.1",
    "async": "^2.1.2",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.0.0",
    "interpret": "^1.0.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "loader-runner": "^2.3.0",
    "loader-utils": "^0.2.16",
    "memory-fs": "~0.4.1",
    "mkdirp": "~0.5.0",
    "node-libs-browser": "^2.0.0",
    "source-map": "^0.5.3",
    "supports-color": "^3.1.0",
    "tapable": "~0.2.5",
    "uglify-js": "^2.8.5",
    "watchpack": "^1.3.1",
    "webpack-sources": "^0.2.3",
    "yargs": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "description": "Packs CommonJs/AMD modules for the browser. Allows to split your codebase into multiple bundles, which can be loaded on demand. Support loaders to preprocess files, i.e. json, jsx, es7, css, less, ... and your custom stuff.",
  "devDependencies": {
    "beautify-lint": "^1.0.3",
    "benchmark": "^2.1.1",
    "bundle-loader": "~0.5.0",
    "codacy-coverage": "^2.0.1",
    "codecov.io": "^0.1.2",
    "coffee-loader": "~0.7.1",
    "coffee-script": "^1.10.0",
    "coveralls": "^2.11.2",
    "css-loader": "~0.25.0",
    "es6-promise-polyfill": "^1.1.1",
    "eslint": "3.12.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^3.0.5",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta",
    "file-loader": "~0.9.0",
    "i18n-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.0",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.5",
    "jade": "^1.11.0",
    "jade-loader": "~0.8.0",
    "js-beautify": "^1.5.10",
    "less": "^2.5.1",
    "less-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "mocha-lcov-reporter": "^1.0.0",
    "nsp": "^2.6.1",
    "raw-loader": "~0.5.0",
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.1",
    "script-loader": "~0.7.0",
    "should": "^11.1.1",
    "simple-git": "^1.65.0",
    "sinon": "^1.17.7",
    "style-loader": "~0.13.0",
    "url-loader": "~0.5.0",
    "val-loader": "~0.5.0",
    "vm-browserify": "~0.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.9.0",
    "worker-loader": "~0.7.0"
  },
  "directories": {},
  "dist": {
    "shasum": "eecc083c18fb7bf958ea4f40b57a6640c5a0cc78",
    "tarball": "https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack/-/webpack-2.3.3.tgz"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4.3.0 <5.0.0 || >=5.10"
  },
  "files": [
    "lib/",
    "bin/",
    "buildin/",
    "hot/",
    "web_modules/",
    "schemas/"
  ],
  "gitHead": "ba24c1b163dc038ed738eb4a57dcb241bf63146d",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/webpack/webpack",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "lib/webpack.js",
  "maintainers": [
    {
      "name": "jhnns",
      "email": "mail@johannesewald.de"
    },
    {
      "name": "sokra",
      "email": "tobias.koppers@googlemail.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "thelarkinn",
      "email": "sean.larkin@cuw.edu"
    }
  ],
  "name": "webpack",
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "readme": "ERROR: No README data found!",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/webpack/webpack.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "appveyor:benchmark": "npm run benchmark",
    "appveyor:test": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules\\mocha\\bin\\mocha --harmony test/*.test.js",
    "beautify-lint": "beautify-lint 'lib/**/*.js' 'hot/**/*.js' 'bin/**/*.js' 'benchmark/*.js' 'test/*.js'",
    "benchmark": "mocha test/*.benchmark.js --harmony -R spec",
    "build:examples": "cd examples && node buildAll.js",
    "cover": "node --harmony ./node_modules/istanbul/lib/cli.js cover -x '**/*.runtime.js' node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- test/*.test.js",
    "cover:min": "node --harmony ./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover -x '**/*.runtime.js' --report lcovonly node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- test/*.test.js",
    "lint": "eslint lib bin hot buildin test/**/webpack.config.js test/binCases/**/test.js examples/**/webpack.config.js",
    "lint-files": "npm run lint && npm run beautify-lint",
    "nsp": "nsp check --output summary",
    "pretest": "npm run lint-files",
    "publish-patch": "npm run lint && npm run beautify-lint && mocha && npm version patch && git push && git push --tags && npm publish",
    "test": "mocha test/*.test.js --harmony --check-leaks",
    "travis:benchmark": "npm run benchmark",
    "travis:lint": "npm run lint-files && npm run nsp",
    "travis:test": "npm run cover:min"
  },
  "version": "2.3.3",
  "web": "lib/webpack.web.js"
}
```

EDIT:
I've come with following solution in the end:
Add this to your package.json file

```
  "scripts" : {
  "build" : "webpack ./entry.js bundle.js"
  }
```

and then type `npm run build` this will still run the local version because npm will first look in `./node_modules/.bin/`

Comment: If it's in `node_modules/.bin` then that sounds like `webpack` was installed locally and not globally. Perhaps try again with `npm install -g webpack`?

Comment: @Trott First I installed it locally but because it wasn't working I installed it globally. And then it worked in PowerShell but output was in C: not in my working folder, so thats why I tried git bash and got to work with locally but I have to use whole command path instead of just using webpack script-1.js /.bundle.js  At the moment I have webpack installed both in folder I'm working with and globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That kind of path is what is used in a git for Windows bash.
See [this issue](https://github.com/iam4x/isomorphic-flux-boilerplate/issues/157#issuecomment-175464483)

> We use cmdr (http://cmder.net/ ) to emulate console on Windows machines.
>   Still we had to modify scripts and separate build to clean and build tasks to get it working.

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "build": "node_modules/.bin/babel-node -- ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --stats --config  ./webpack/prod.config.js",
    ...
},
```

You can see a similar instruction in [this project `package.json`](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate/commit/c68935926c6d4ebcb5d59a35b9880374d05b9b3d):

```
"build-main": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node -r babel-register ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack --config webpack.config.electron.js --progress --profile --colors",
```

Comment: After reading every link you added quite a few times, I'm still not sure what am I suppose to do. Am I suppose to add "build-main: ..." you wrote in my package json located in node_modules ? Also I added my package.json to my question, so you can see it for yourself.

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 Yes, the point of those links was to illutrate that, apparently, you had ti use and specify such paths (`./node_modules/webpack/bin`) and not rely on just the command alone (`webpack`)